# Ranking based on value importance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say you're given this random data:
[image]

What formula can be used to rank items; assuming higher numbers in *Performance Score* have highest value, and lowest prices in *Price* have highest value?

Comment: You should at least also show us what the expected ordering is.  Also, please note that it is generally preferable _not_ to link to external images, because those links can break.  Instead, include all data directly in the question.

Comment: We can help translate your ranking logic into a formula - not to help you determine a ranking method. This is not a formula question. How are we supposed to know the weight (importance) of each input?

Comment: @swiggity-swag something else you should always include are what approaches you've already tried and what about them haven't worked. To build on underboy's comment, simply asking for someone to provide you a solution with minimal effort on your end is typically frowned upon on Stack Exchange forums. For help with editing and future questions, consult [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why don't you sort on the two columns? B descending and C ascending? If you want a particular number for rank, you need to know how to calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that follows your logic. However, this assumes that cost and performance are equally important.

1. Rank Performance (Negatively Related: Higher Performance =  Lower Rank)
2. Rank Cost (Positively Related: Lower Cost = Lower Rank)
3. Sum the ranks (Lower the sum, the better the rank)
4. Rank the sum of ranks

In bottom photo, you can use the highlighted equations and just drop down as needed. Make sure to change the locked references `($$)` to fit your entire range.

[image]

[image]